# ValueError: time data '07-24-2018 16:40: 0' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S ' (match)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
data2['DateTime'].head()
2    07-24-2018 16:40: 0
3    07-24-2018 16:45: 0
4    07-24-2018 16:50: 0
5    07-24-2018 16:55: 0
6    07-24-2018 18: 0: 0
Name: DateTime, dtype: object
```

Is this error due to the missing zero's in the dataframe? I should 'pad' the single zeros in dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer you looked upstream to find out where and why those spaces are being introduced and fix them.

But in the meantime,

```
pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'].str.replace(' 0', '0', regex=False))
```

Or, if you need to be a little more explicit,

```
pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime.str.replace(r'(?<=:)\s0', '0'))
```

```
2   2018-07-24 16:40:00
3   2018-07-24 16:45:00
4   2018-07-24 16:50:00
5   2018-07-24 16:55:00
6   2018-07-24 18:00:00
Name: DateTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you, this code does not work as intended on my data. I'm taking your advice and going back 'upstream' to see why the data does not *always* display two digits in the time field.

Comment: Ok, I went back to original source, financial futures data in C++, and added the correct code there to pad single digits. This solved the issue. Thank you again for bringing that suggestion up.